# Android capture video of connected device with ADT

Tags: android

Is there a possibility to capture a video of the screen of a connected Android device with ADT? Or is there a better possibility? I need it as a demo for the Play Store like a lot of other apps have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called Android ScreenCast, it's open source and you can find it here : https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. Would be nice if Google add a possibility to easily record a movie with sound with ADB.